# Select limited rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

So this is fairly common knowledge to select rows from multiple tables and stack the results on top of each other:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION
...
```

However, if I want only a limited number of rows from each table, then how should I write it?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2 LIMIT 2
UNION
...
```

Clearly doesn't work.

Note that in my case, I have 51 tables, all with the same exact columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be work this way

```
( SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 2  )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM table2 LIMIT 2 )
UNION
...
```

Comment: That's it? Just put brackets on them?! Hahaha! I spent like the past couple of hours vexing myself to find a solution! Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping the query with ()  you force the rdbms to consider the result and not to perfrorm only the query .. itself  .. in this wya you are union the resutl not the query ..

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know such a separation between query and results existed. But thinking about how RDBMS works, it does make sense.

Comment: Is not easy understand this difference  .. but when you know  .. you can build and use dinamic query  .. in a easy an performing way ..